# Can i use instances of a laravel model instead of facades?

Tags: laravel, model

I'm wondering whether it is possible/advisable to use instances of a laravel model instead of using the Facade. Why all this trouble? I have a model which will be used with many tables, and i want to be setting the model's `table` automatically using the constructor. Is it possible/advisable, or what is the best approach of achieving the same end?

I have researched around with no much success.

UPDATE
THis is the scenario: an exam system, where different exams are "created". after an exam is created, a table is created in the database under the name `Exam_#`, where `#` is the ID of the exam. I want to access all exam from one model: `Exam`, but you see the particular table the model is to use can vary significantly, so we cannot set the `table` variable statically. The model shall not know the table it will use until it(the model) is called. So thats why i was wondering whether i can be passing the `ID` of the exam when i am calling the `model` or something like that. I hope my question is now more clear.

Comment: Why not just create one such base model, then create a model for each of your tables extending the base one.

Comment: the tables are created automatically..well, let me edit the question to give more specific info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of this, Laravel is still PHP... Anything you can do in PHP can be done in Laravel.

**is (it) possible/advisable to use instances of a laravel model instead of using the Facade?**

You can achieve exactly the same results using an instance of the model as you would using the static facade.

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user2 = new User();
$user2 = $user2->find(1);
```

Both instances of the above model contain the same results.

Is it advisable? I really don't like the static facades at all, they bring with them more trouble than they are worth, especially when it comes to testing (despite being able to mock them, they create tight coupling where most of us need loose coupling). My answer to this would be: don't use the facades at all.

**What is the best approach of achieving the same end?**

As @JoelHinz suggested, create a base model with common properties and then use the models as they are intended. i.e. ONE table to ONE model and create the relationships between them. Don't use the same model for multiple tables, this is not how Laravel models were intended and you will lose a lot of the power Eloquent provides by taking the approach you mentioned.

**Updates from comments**
To get you started with testing in Laravel this is a good end to end tutorial [Tutsplus Laravel4 + Backbone](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/combining-laravel-4-and-backbone--net-31745). Ignore the backbone part, what you're interested in is the testing parts that start about a 1/3rd of the way down the page. This will get you testing controllers straight away and introduce you to the repository pattern to create testable DAL structures.

Once you get the hang of writing tests, it becomes very easy to write a unit test for anything. It may seem like a scary subject, but that is purely down to not understanding how it works, it really is quite simple. Take a look at the PHPUnit documentation as well, it is an excellent resource.

Comment: thanks. if `Laravel===PHP`, and instances can provide all the functionalities of a facade, i think i will be using instances in my particular issue. but i will also consider what you said above about base models.min fact, given the last partof your sanswer, that is what is most preferred.
PS: you talked about testing. That term usually scares me as i dont know much about it or how to code for testability. do you have a link you can point me to that can help me out on that?

Comment: Added some stuff to the answer for you.